# Get places photos from Factual API

Tags: php, json, api, google-places-api, factual

I am using Factual API to list places and restaurants from its restaurants-us schema. 
I can retrieve all the required fields of information except the images of the places.

Is there any way to get the images from Factual API? Or any other way to get them at least by passing the Factual latitude and longitude coordinates to Google Places API?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use CROSSWALK for places

http://developer.factual.com/places-crosswalk/