# Factual API restaurant images

Tags: factual

Is it possible to get pictures of the restaurant from the Factual API? I have not been able to find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get places photos from Factual API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333426/get-places-photos-from-factual-api)

Answer (score 1):

The Factual API does not store pictures of their restaurant data.  To see what attributes are stored for restaurants, go here: https://www.factual.com/products/global#restaurants

It seems like the Google Places API will better suite your needs, for more information visit the following: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro

The following answer recommends trying Factual's Crosswalk feature: [Get places photos from Factual API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333426/get-places-photos-from-factual-api)